# CountRows SSRS 2012 threw an error :

Tags: t-sql, count, ssrs-2012

I want to count the number of rows in my result DataSet, I put in my DataSet a calculated field with this expression :

```
=CountRows("DataSet1")
```

But I have the following error message:

"The expression used for the calculated field '=CountRows' includes an aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous or lookup function. Aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous and lookup functions cannot be used in calculated field expressions."
What should I do ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

> =CountRows(nothing) or =CountRows("GroupingName") or RowNuber("DataSet1") or RowNuber("GroupingName")

One of these should work